# How to add arrow in jquery connections

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I used jquery connector - https://github.com/musclesoft/jquery-connections to connect two draggable DIV element.
**Problem**: It should represent the direction of flow in the connector. Need to add an arrow to jquery connector.

Comment: I don't think it is possible unless you modify the library code. your plugin adding the lines as borders of objects. I don't think it is possible to add arrows to borders. you will need to add an extra object somhow rotated to align the end of line and have two visible borders.

Comment: You could do this with an SVG element if you wanted.

Comment: could anyone share a link to any method mentioned above?

Comment: A few jsPlumb questions, they may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518763/how-to-connect-to-endpoint-using-jsplumb

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246859/connecting-jquery-ui-dialogs-with-a-line-using-jsplumb

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345832/cant-set-image-to-jsplumb-endpoint